# Dynamic method overload depending on enum in TypeScript (indexable method signature instead of properties)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this:

```
enum Command {
    CMD1 = 0,
    CMD2,
    CMD3
}
namespace Callbacks {
    export type CMD1 = (arg1:number) => void;
    export type CMD2 = (arg1:string) => void;
    export type CMD3 = (arg1:boolean) => void;
}
class Thingy {
    //[...] THINGS [...]//
    
    emit(command:Command.CMD1, ...args:Parameters<Callbacks.CMD1>):void;
    emit(command:Command.CMD2, ...args:Parameters<Callbacks.CMD2>):void;
    emit(command:Command.CMD3, ...args:Parameters<Callbacks.CMD3>):void;
    emit(command:Command, ...args:any[]) {
        this._emit(command, args);
    }

    on(command:Command.CMD1, cb:Callbacks.CMD1):void;
    on(command:Command.CMD2, cb:Callbacks.CMD2):void;
    on(command:Command.CMD3, cb:Callbacks.CMD3):void;
    on(command:Command, cb:Function) {
        this.events.set(command, cb);
    }
}
```

With this I plan to have a `Command` enum and a matching `Callbacks` object that will define the same argument signature to be sent and received. Is working as expected, but the more commands I add, the more cumbersome is getting to duplicate each `emit` and `on`.

I thought that maybe is there a way to have one `emit` and `on` definition that will get the `Command` keys dynamically, but I'm having a lot of problems finding a way. The closest thing I've created is this:

```
type CB = {
    CMD1:(arg1:number) => void;
    CMD2:(arg1:string) => void;
    CMD3:(arg1:boolean) => void;
}

type CBS = {
    [P in keyof typeof Command]:CB[P];
}

class Thingy implements CBS {...}
```

The thing is that this creates a `CMD1(...)`, `CMD2(...)`, `CMD3(...)` signature. I think that I'm close but I don't know how to convert it to a `on(...)` signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, taking the [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350994/1525495) as a starting point.

```
export enum Command {
    CMD1 = 0,
    CMD2,
    CMD3
}
interface Callbacks {
    [Command.CMD1]: (arg1:number) => void;
    [Command.CMD2]: (arg1:boolean) => void;
    [Command.CMD3]: (arg1:string) => void;
}

export class Thingy {
    /* [...] */
    
    emit<CN extends Command, A extends Parameters<Callbacks[CN]>>(command: CN, ...args: A) {
        this._emit(command, args);
    }

    on<CN extends Command, CB extends Callbacks[CN]>(command: CN, cb: CB) {
        this.events.set(command, cb);
    }
}
```

This way I still keep having a `Command` (usually a number) as the first parameter instead of a string. The key was to set the `Callbacks` interface to the enum values instead of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using generics. Here's a quick and dirty solution

```
interface Callbacks {
    CMD1(arg1: number): void
    CMD2(arg1: string): void
    CMD3(arg1: boolean): void
}
type CommandName = keyof Callbacks

class Thingy {
    //[...] THINGS [...]//

    emit<CN extends CommandName, A extends Parameters<Callbacks[CN]>>(command: CN, ...args: A) {
        this._emit(command, args)
    }

    on<CN extends CommandName, CB extends Callbacks[CN]>(command: CN, cb: CB) {
        this.events.set(command, cb)
    }
}
```

Let's take a look at the `on` function. We're introducing a generic type `CN` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the type `CommandName`, which we earlier define as being the key of the `Callbacks` object. Thus, `CN` may only ever be `CMD1`, `CMD2`, or `CMD3`. From there, we see that the second generic type `CB` is constrained to whatever the type of `Callback[CN]` is; for `CN = 'CMD1'` this will be `(arg1: number) => void`.

It is a similar concept for the `emit` function, except this time we are extracting the `Parameters` of the function.

When we call the `emit` or `on` function, we are required to pass a valid command name as the first argument, and from there Typescript can figure out what the second argument must be:

```
new Thingy().emit('CMD2', 'test') // MUST be a string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYYEaINYDOyA3gFDIVoCyAIgIwAUcUA5nQFzIgCuAtttACUnAG4B7YABNylVLQBMTVh2QEwUUC2HJxUmRTk0AzEradsYsRghwQ23dIC+pMAE8ADilRjevW5IA5OF4UAF5kPAhXMRg0TBx8AlJSBAw4AiIAFQALTVcSfWQAeiKAbQA6SoBdZEyACQBJAIBxAGVkCuqS5MpkCF5gMAAeVAC+gA9IEEkib19-IJCAGmQAQQmpmeQABWZgiEgoAhH43ARCUtGqgD5rhgQfP2nOUZXK8uYWAk5VwQLe3pgXIEcoAfX6g3uj38K0+BEEhWchTEIBGYwgkwg01m0OmiwgK1QACENlitugsGcLlc7g95s80AEVghsC8iX8yADKEDgCCICIsWAQQQDlD6ZJmdgEb1nEiSrUAKKtTKtFIotTIMDIcIgCAAd1quRALFcDARYHKELADAA5IY6DaVnQ-vKAPIAaWQMDEUC4fAEUBcloG1rttAdKxtDpdRWQADE4MAMERvb61BpjbCiBjPAhINILSjbfbHchTH9QtdkJ9ymAxNsoBAELzgEXBDHq6xkLzq37+NAsxNc-mgA)

Comment: Hm, that's clever. Thank you. Btw this will force the command to be a string. I want it to be the enum, to avoid accessing the object unnecessarily when sending the command.